# Create a segmentation picture with each object class rendered in different color ?

Tags: python

I am using the blender to create a visual parking scene model, by using the python script the model could produces a RGB picture of the parking scene as well as the depth image, both are showing below.

[image]

[image]

I am just wondering would it possible to also create a segmentation image which separates each object class with a color, for example all the car object are in red, all the ground are in blue, all the building are in grey, like the examples

[image][image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give each object a unique 'pass index'. You can use the compositor, the Object Info node, and some math nodes to convert it to a colour.

This happens when you divide the object index by the maximum index you're using (to get it to a 0-1 value), and apply it to a diffuse material:

[image: As diffuse material]

By using a Colour Ramp you can take that 0-1 value and map it to discrete colours:

[image: With colour ramp as diffuse material]

By swapping out the Diffuse shader with an Emission shader, you just get the straight colour values:

[image: With colour ramp as emission shader]

This is the final material:

[image: Cycles material node setup]

This is the blend file I used:
[image]

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/object_info.html) for more info.

Comment: is there any tutorial for this ?

Comment: I've added example images, the node setup, and an example blend file for you.

Answer (score 9):

A python package [`bpycv`](https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv) can render annotations for instance segmentation and panoptic segmentation.

First, follow the [instruction](https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv#install) to install `bpycv` in Blender.

Here is a simple code to show how to get segmentation annotations. Copy-paste this code to `Text Editor` and click `Run Script` button(or `Alt+P`)

```py
import cv2
import bpy
import bpycv
import random

# remove all MESH objects
[bpy.data.objects.remove(obj) for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.type == "MESH"]

for inst_id in range(1, 20):
    # create cube and sphere as instance at random location
    location = [random.random() * 4 - 2 for _ in range(3)]
    if inst_id % 2:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.5, location=location)
    else:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.5, location=location)
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    # set each instance a unique inst_id, which is used to generate instance annotation.
    obj["inst_id"] = inst_id

# render image, instance annoatation and depth in one line code
result = bpycv.render_data()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("demo-rgb.jpg", result["image"])
cv2.imwrite("demo-inst.png", result["inst"])
# normalizing depth
cv2.imwrite("demo-depth.png", result["depth"] / result["depth"].max() * 255)

# visualization inst|rgb|depth for human
cv2.imwrite("demo-vis(inst|rgb|depth).jpg", result.vis())
```

The visualization result of instance segmentation, RGB image and depth
[image]

More detial: [`bpycv`](https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv)

Comment: doesnt work for me ```No module named boxx```

Comment: @cxnt1 just install boxx by ‘“your blender python” -m pip install boxx’

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain how to install it, as I dont really understand... ```No module named 'bpycv.boxx```

Comment: @cxnt1  I don't know the details of the error. Could you please provide more context.(you can send me email: ylxx@live.com )