# How to obtain segmentation map using script

Tags: python

I want to obtain 2D segmentation map of objects using python script. So effectively I am interested in the same problem as in here: [Create a segmentation picture with each object class rendered in different color ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80906/create-a-segmentation-picture-with-each-object-class-rendered-in-different-color) but I want to do it in python (so that I can automatically generate many examples)

Comment: What do you mean by "many examples" here? Many blend file? Many camera angles? Other?

Comment: I think Blender 2.8 cryptomatte could be what you're looking for. I'm not entirely sure what part you'd like to automate with python, you'd need to give us some more information.

Comment: @lemon - yes, seeing the scene from different camera views for example. And then doing the segmentation for different scenes. I can generate different scenes, views myself already, but I have problem with getting the 2D segmentation

Comment: Take a look at the new answer from Yang on the question you linked; it shows a library + demo script for doing this in Python.

Comment: Thx, this is exactly what I needed