# Blender RGB masking with segmentation. How to? If possible

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, color, masking

I have a 3d small garden with 15 plants. Each plant have leaf objects. Formally they are just a leaf objects with different XYZ location/rotation/scale.
[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K387w.jpg)

I want to get something similar to this image:

[image]

I need to make an RGB mask of my garden? How do I make it?

I'm thinking of creating a new materials and give them random coloring and then apply materials on my leaf objects, that would work too I suppose, but I believe there should be an easier and better way.

Here's my script:

```
for obj in [o for o in source_collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']:
       for i in range(1):
           for obj in [o for o in source_collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']:
               # get a copy of the object
               new_obj = duplicate( obj, destination_collection, False )
               # ** Make your random transforms here ** 
               RGBMask = bpy.data.materials.new("RGBMask")
               bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(RGBMask)
               bpy.data.materials["RGBMask"].diffuse_color = random(), random(), random(), random() 
               rotateX = round(uniform(-20,20), 2)
               rotateY = round(uniform(10,50), 2)
               rotateZ = randint(-760,760)
               scaleX = round(uniform(0.3,1), 2)
               scaleY = round(uniform(0.3,1), 2)
               scaleZ = round(uniform(0.3,1), 2)
               new_obj.scale = ( scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ )
               new_obj.rotation_euler = (radians(rotateX),radians(rotateY),radians(rotateZ))
```

It creates new material called RGBMask, but applies it for all of my objects, but I need to have each leaf have it's own color. I'm new to python and blender, so any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I believe cryptomatte is what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml1Kic4VopA

Comment: @rjg it's very close to what I want, figuring out now how to use it. Thanks for the tip!!!!

Comment: You can use the [vision_blender](https://github.com/Cartucho/vision_blender) add-on for this. It crates segmentations masks for you when you render an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution: [Create a segmentation picture with each object class rendered in different color ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80906/create-a-segmentation-picture-with-each-object-class-rendered-in-different-color/80925).
It worked for me.

Moreover, if you want sharp edges you can set `render properties -> film -> filter size` for eevee to `0.00`.